# Send data in json and display in datatable

Tags: php, ajax, datatables, datatables-1.10

Can anyone help me with how do I display my data in datatables? I'm trying the server-side datatables but I can't get it. Anyways, I can return my data in JSON but I always got this error: DataTables warning: table id=show-employee-table - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

These what I've tried:

**ajax.js**

```
var url = '../../class/functions.php';

function show_employee() {
    var data = { action : 'Show Employee Table' };
    $("#show-employee-table").dataTable({
        ajax: {
            type: 'POST', url: url, data: data
        }
    })
}
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php 
    include 'config.php';

    switch($_POST['action']) {
        case 'Show Employee Table':
            $data->show_employee_table();
        break;
    }

?>
```

**class.php**

```
<?php
    include 'controller.php';

    class db extends Controller {
        //Get all employees
        public function get_employee() {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_accounts WHERE employee_role_id = 2");
            return $query;
        }

        public function show_employee_table() {
            foreach($this->get_employee() as $row): ?>
                <?php $data = $row; ?>
                <?php $employee_status = ($row['employee_status'] == "Active") ? '<span class="badge badge-success">Active</span>' : '<span class="badge badge-danger">Not Active</span>';?>
                    
            <?php endforeach;
    
            echo json_encode(['data' => $data]);
        }
    }
?>
```

**controller.php**

```
<?php
    class Controller {
        public $host                = 'localhost';
        public $database_username   = 'root';
        public $database_password   = '';
        public $database_name       = 'try_db';
        public $db;
        
        function __construct() {
            $this->connection();
        }

        private function connection() {
            $this->db = new mysqli($this->host, $this->database_username, $this->database_password, $this->database_name);
            if($this->db->connect_error) {
                echo 'Could not connect to the database!';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    ob_start();
    include 'class.php';
    //include 'init.php';
    $data = new db();
?>
```

Comment: Why do you have    `<?php` tag on class.php? If you post a complete file of class.php may be I can help to you.

Comment: I'll edit it. Wait a minute.

Comment: Edited. Can you check it? Thanks so much! @ThamiraMadusanka

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is to fetch my data or records into the table either by ajax or page load and then call datatables after the ajax is successful or done like so.

```
$.ajax
   ({
       url:URL,
       type:"post",
       data:DATA,
       success:function(response)
       {
        //response should be the data of rows intended to be inserted into the table

         $("#show-employee-table").html(response)
           
         $("#show-employee-table").dataTable()
       }
   })
```

No need to return a JSON data

Answer (score 0):

Try to update ajax.js like this

```
 $("#show-employee-table").dataTable({
           "processing": true,
           "serverSide": true,
           "ajax": {
               "url": url,
               "type": "POST",
               "data": data
       },
    })
```

Full example:

index.php

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>DataTable Demo</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container mt-3">
        <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Middle name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Middle name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

           
                $('#example').DataTable( {
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "Functions.php",
                        "type": "POST",
                        "data": { action : 'Show Employee Table' }
                    },
                    "columns": [
                        { "data": "first_name" },
                        { "data": "middle_name" },
                        { "data": "last_name" }
                    ]
                } );
            } );
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

DBConnect.php

```
<?php

class DBConnect
{
    public $host                = 'localhost';
    public $database_username   = 'root';
    public $database_password   = '';
    public $database_name       = 'try_db';
    public $db;

    public function connect() {
        $this->db = new mysqli($this->host, $this->database_username, $this->database_password, $this->database_name);
        if($this->db->connect_error) {
            echo 'Could not connect to the database!';
        }
        return $this->db;
    }
}
```

Controller.php

```
<?php
include 'DBConnect.php';

class Controller
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $connect = new DBConnect();
        $this->db = $connect->connect();
    }

    public function getEmployeeDetails()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM employees";
        $result = $this->db->query($sql);
        $response = [];
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $response[] = $row;
            }
        }
        // in this total records and page number should be dynamic for this example I just hardcoded it
        echo json_encode([ "draw" => 1, "recordsTotal" => 2, "recordsFiltered" => 2, 'data' => $response]);
    }
}
```

Functions.php

```
<?php
include 'Controller.php';
$controller = new Controller();
$action = $_POST['action'];

switch ($action) {
    case 'Show Employee Table':
        $controller->getEmployeeDetails();
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: Not working. Still I got this error: DataTables warning: table id=show-employee-table - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

Comment: I think the problem is the way you structure your code. It's hard to understand. So I create a sample projects which is much similar to yours. So I'll edit this answer. Hope it will help to you. :)

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error

> error: DataTables warning: table id=show-employee-table - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

is a pretty common one. In fact they have a dedicated page for the cause and diagnosis of this error.

See : https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3

Simply put - you can only initialise DataTable once and subsequent call (with options) would result in error.

you have options though, please see the doc.

As for the answer try this.

**controller.php**

```php
<?php

class Controller {
    public $host                = 'localhost';
    public $database_username   = 'root';
    public $database_password   = '';
    public $database_name       = 'try_db';
    public $db;
    
    function __construct() {
        $this->connection();
    }

    private function connection() {
        $this->db = new mysqli(
            $this->host, 
            $this->database_username, 
            $this->database_password, 
            $this->database_name
        );

        if($this->db->connect_error) {
            die 'Could not connect to the database!';
        }
    }
}
```

**config.php**

```php
<?php

session_start();
ob_start();
require_once 'class.php';
$data = new db();
```

**class.php**

```php
<?php

require_once 'controller.php';

class db extends Controller {

    /** Get all employees */
    public function get_employee() {
        if (!($query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_accounts WHERE employee_role_id = 2"))) {
            die "Could not execute query"
        };

        return $query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }

    public function show_employee_table() {
        echo json_encode(['data' => $this->get_employee()]);
    }
}
```

**functions.php**

```php
<?php 
    require_once 'config.php';

    switch($_POST['action']) {
        case 'Show Employee Table':
            $data->show_employee_table();
        break;
    }
```

**ajax.js**

```js
var url = '../../class/functions.php';
var dtTable = null;

$(function() {
    dtTable = $("#show-employee-table").dataTable({
        ajax: {
            type: 'POST', 
            url: url, 
            data: {
                action : 'Show Employee Table'
            }
        }
    });
})

function refreshDT() {
    dtTable.ajax.reload();
}
```